# Building a Jar file in Intellij

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, build, jar

I am new to Java and I am using Intellij. I have a src folder where I wrote my Java program. I have to build my Jar file but I am struggling so far.

I have built the Jar file and I try running this in the command line :

`java -jar Project.jar input.json output.json`

But I have this error when running the program :

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["employee_type"] is not a number.
```

I am not sure to understand why it does that. When I run my code by configuring the arguments and when debugging, the program works without any problem, but not the build.

I have these libraries but I am not sure if all of them are useful:

```
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
```

Here is my JSON file :

```
{
 "id_employee":123456789,
 "employee_type":2,
 "min_pay":"35.47 $",
 "max_pay":"72.03 $"
}
```

And here bit of the code that reads the JSON file, the error happens at the 4th line :

```
String myJSON = loadFileIntoString(args[1], "UTF-8");
JSONObject jsonEmployee = JSONObject.fromObject(myJSON);
int employeeID = jsonEmploye.getInt("id_employee");
int employeeType = jsonEmploye.getInt("employee_type");
String minHourlyRateString = jsonEmploye.getString("min_pay");
String maxHourlyRateString = jsonEmploye.getString("max_pay");
```

I have stuggled here for a while, not fully understanding if the build is wrong or anything else. I tried to follow the tutorials to build correctly the program into a jar file, but it still gives me the error that it can't read correctly my JSON file. My code doesn't seems to be an issue since the run and debug works as expected, so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome in the dev community.

I don't have all the details but when I see your code, in my opinion the issue is on the line "String myJSON = loadFileIntoString(args[1], "UTF-8");"

Indeed your command line : `java -jar Project.jar input.json output.json`
but the args[1] is not the input.json but the output.json, if you want to read the input.json file you should use args[0].